# Getting this alert on adding build for testing in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight, app-store-connect

[image]I am trying to add a new build to TestFlight for testing to a group of users. But everything it is showing me this alert. I am unable to find out what can be the issue. Please help me out, if anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: Got the issue. I had uploaded build with Adhoc provisioning profile, that is why it was showing error. Once I uploaded new build with AppStore provisioning profile, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in and out of AppStore Connect and quitting the browser?

Comment: This didn't worked. But I got the issue. Thanks for the help @Brandon.